Adding a fresh zfs sub-dataset pri_zp/Z1/Z99-future to pri_zp/Z1, and resuming recursive replication to sec_zp/Z1
I have set up and replicated the OpenZFS dataset pri_zp/Z1 (with pri_zp/Z1/Z00-initial) to sec_zp/Z1 using a zfs send -R.
But then (months later) when I try to create (and replicate) a newer data set, called pri_zp/Z1/Z99-future, the replication to sec_zp/Z1 fails.
How do I add a fresh sub data set pri_zp/Z1/Z99-future, and enable its recursive replication?
Below is an example trace of the zfs commands that demonstrate the hiccup I encountered.
A. Setup Z1 base with Z00-initial:
# zfs create pri_zp/Z1
# zfs create pri_zp/Z1/Z00-initial

# zfs snapshot -r pri_zp/Z1@ssA
# zfs send -V -R pri_zp/Z1@ssA | zfs receive -d sec_zp
full send of pri_zp/Z1@ssA estimated size is 79.1K
full send of pri_zp/Z1/Z00-initial@ssA estimated size is 78.6K
total estimated size is 158K

B. Send an next snapshot, ssB:
# zfs snapshot -r pri_zp/Z1@ssB
# zfs send -V -R -I pri_zp/Z1@ss{A,B} | zfs receive -d sec_zp
send from @ssA to pri_zp/Z1@ssB estimated size is 624B
send from @ssA to pri_zp/Z1/Z00-initial@ssB estimated size is 624B
total estimated size is 1.22K

C. Start integration of Z99-future:
# zfs create pri_zp/Z1/Z99-future

# zfs snapshot -r pri_zp/Z1@ssC
# zfs send -V -I pri_zp/Z1@ss{B,C} | zfs receive -d sec_zp
send from @ssB to pri_zp/Z1@ssC estimated size is 61.1K
total estimated size is 61.1K

Everything working fine until here.  But now I need to send the initial ssC snapshot of pri_zp/Z1/Z99-future@ssC.  (It's not an incremental)
This next zfs command probably triggers the problem, but it cannot be done recursively:
# zfs send -V pri_zp/Z1/Z99-future@ssC | zfs receive -d sec_zp

D. Here the problem manifests itself:
# zfs snapshot -r pri_zp/Z1@ssD
# zfs send -V -R -I pri_zp/Z1@ss{C,D} | zfs receive -d sec_zp
send from @ssC to pri_zp/Z1@ssD estimated size is 624B
send from @ssC to pri_zp/Z1/Z99-future@ssD estimated size is 624B
send from @ssC to pri_zp/Z1/Z00-initial@ssD estimated size is 624B
total estimated size is 1.83K
cannot receive incremental stream: destination sec_zp/Z1 has been modified
since most recent snapshot

The specific dataset change caused by zfs send -V pri_zp/Z1/Z99-future@ssC:
# zfs diff sec_zp/Z1@ssC
+       /sec_zp/Z1/Z99-future
M       /sec_zp/Z1/
-       /sec_zp/Z1/Z99-future
-       /sec_zp/Z1/Z99-future/<xattrdir>
-       /sec_zp/Z1/Z99-future/<xattrdir>/security.selinux

Also:
# zfs list -r -t all -S creation sec_zp/Z1      
NAME                        USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
sec_zp/Z1/Z99-future         96K  1.22T    96K  /sec_zp/Z1/Z99-future
sec_zp/Z1@ssC                64K      -   104K  -
sec_zp/Z1/Z99-future@ssC      0B      -    96K  -
sec_zp/Z1@ssB                 0B      -    96K  -
sec_zp/Z1/Z00-initial@ssB     0B      -    96K  -
sec_zp/Z1/Z00-initial        96K  1.22T    96K  /sec_zp/Z1/Z00-initial
sec_zp/Z1                   416K  1.22T    96K  /sec_zp/Z1
sec_zp/Z1@ssA                 0B      -    96K  -
sec_zp/Z1/Z00-initial@ssA     0B      -    96K 

Any hints are welcomed.

Update: This seems to work.
A. create initial "sub" zfs datasets:
# zfs create pri_zp/Z1
# zfs create pri_zp/Z1/Z00-initial
# zfs snapshot -r pri_zp/Z1@ssA
# zfs send -V -R pri_zp/Z1@ssA | zfs receive -d sec_zp
full send of pri_zp/Z1@ssA estimated size is 79.1K
full send of pri_zp/Z1/Z00-initial@ssA estimated size is 78.6K
total estimated size is 158K

B. more example snapshots:
# zfs snapshot -r pri_zp/Z1@ssB
# zfs send -V -R -I pri_zp/Z1@ss{A,B} | zfs receive -d sec_zp
send from @ssA to pri_zp/Z1@ssB estimated size is 624B
send from @ssA to pri_zp/Z1/Z00-initial@ssB estimated size is 624B
total estimated size is 1.22K

C. prep for future stapshot:
# zfs snapshot -r pri_zp/Z1@ssC
# zfs send -V -R -I pri_zp/Z1@ss{B,C} | zfs receive -d sec_zp
send from @ssB to pri_zp/Z1@ssC estimated size is 624B
send from @ssB to pri_zp/Z1/Z00-initial@ssC estimated size is 624B
total estimated size is 1.22K
# zfs create pri_zp/Z1/Z99-future
# zfs snapshot pri_zp/Z1/Z99-future@ssC
# zfs send -V pri_zp/Z1/Z99-future@ssC | zfs receive -d sec_zp

Repair and reset secondary sec_zp/Z1@ssC:
# zfs rollback sec_zp/Z1@ssC

D. more example snapshots, but including pri_zp/Z1/Z99-future:
# zfs snapshot -r pri_zp/Z1@ssD
# zfs send -V -R -I pri_zp/Z1@ss{C,D} | zfs receive -d sec_zp
send from @ssC to pri_zp/Z1@ssD estimated size is 61.1K
send from @ssC to pri_zp/Z1/Z00-initial@ssD estimated size is 624B
send from @ssC to pri_zp/Z1/Z99-future@ssD estimated size is 624B
total estimated size is 62.3K

Review outcome:
# zfs diff sec_zp/Z1@ssC
M   /sec_zp/Z1/
+   /sec_zp/Z1/Z99-future
+   /sec_zp/Z1/Z99-future/<xattrdir>
+   /sec_zp/Z1/Z99-future/<xattrdir>/security.selinux

# zfs diff sec_zp/Z1@ssD

# zfs list -r -t all -S creation sec_zp/Z1
NAME                        USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
sec_zp/Z1@ssD                 0B      -   104K  -
sec_zp/Z1/Z00-initial@ssD     0B      -    96K  -
sec_zp/Z1/Z99-future@ssD      0B      -    96K  -
sec_zp/Z1/Z99-future         96K  1.22T    96K  /sec_zp/Z1/Z99-future
sec_zp/Z1/Z99-future@ssC      0B      -    96K  -
sec_zp/Z1@ssC                 0B      -    96K  -
sec_zp/Z1/Z00-initial@ssC     0B      -    96K  -
sec_zp/Z1@ssB                 0B      -    96K  -
sec_zp/Z1/Z00-initial@ssB     0B      -    96K  -
sec_zp/Z1                   352K  1.22T   104K  /sec_zp/Z1
sec_zp/Z1/Z00-initial        96K  1.22T    96K  /sec_zp/Z1/Z00-initial
sec_zp/Z1@ssA                 0B      -    96K  -
sec_zp/Z1/Z00-initial@ssA     0B      -    96K  -

The trick is to rollback a prior sec_zp/Z1@ssC whenever a "sub" zfs dataset is added to pri_zp! ... but I do wonder if there a zfs send option (that I have missed) that does this already?
p.s. I also wonder what /sec_zp/Z1/Z99-future/<xattrdir>/security.selinux is doing? (And if it's bad this xattrdir got stripped?)
For the record: pri_zp is running zfs-2.1.15-3, and sec_zp is running zfs-2.2.3-1~bpo12+1~rpt1.
